# If i use two or more lighters to heat an iron spoon, will it melt?

Tags: thermodynamics

If i start heating an iron spoon with one lighter and i start adding more lighters to that "heating system", can the temperature increase so high that it would melt the spoon ?

Comment: With a butane torch you can certainly solder and braze. Too many lighters and your fingers will get really hot...

Comment: I probably think you won’t be able to. That’s because you are adding energy ( which converts to heat ) to the system. But that energy is a separate entity not part of the lighter that is already on. Because of this the energy used is only going process more energy at the same rate giving the same temperature. If you have to melt the spoon you have to have a lighter that burns at a higher temperature. By having multiple lighters at lower temperature will only heat more area of the spoon not raise the net temperature.

Comment: AFAIK adding lighters won't really increase temperature (signifigantly) of the total flame.  It should increase the total heat transfer; but that should mostly because you have more of the volume being heated.  You can't really change the fuel, so combustion temperature won't change much (unless the amount that gets combust ed starts to change a lot too).

Comment: Melting iron is not so easy. Melting temperature is rather high. There is a reason why the iron age (iron T(melt)=1538 ˚C) of a region often occurred long after its bronze age  (bronze T(melt)=950 ˚C). The ability to reach temperatures high enough to melt iron was quite an accomplishment historically.

Comment: Related: [Could a candle theoretically melt iron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272893/27542)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Butane lighters claim a flame temperature of 1430C. Iron melts at 1538C. No chance, however many lighters you use.

Comment: But if you have a silver spoon (don't keep it in your mouth, you'll burn your lips)...

Comment: There are also stainless steel grades that melt below 1430 C. I have no idea if they're the ones used for silverware.